# whats the method to calculate and display the disc size inserted in f-drive?

Tags: c#, .net, diskspace

how can i calculate the total disc space available + free space + used space in the DVD/CD inserted in f-drive.. and display the result on the label...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.IO;

DriveInfo fDrive = new DriveInfo(@"F:\");
Console.WriteLine(fDrive.AvailableFreeSpace);
Console.WriteLine(fDrive.TotalSize);
```

For other properties, check this [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo_properties.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use GetDriveInfo from the FileSystem class. You need to reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic DLL.

Comment: Or just use DriveInfo.GetDrives(), that way you don't have to reference the VB library.